# Developing a web app to log messages from GPS device

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, google-cloud-platform

this is my first question here and I realize this question might be open ended, but I'm looking for specific solutions, and any solution would be accepted.
I have GPS devices which send data packets to an IP on a port, both of which I can configure. I wish to use one of Google's, Amazon's or Microsoft's offering of cloud services. I am using python. Here is an implementation I found online :-
https://github.com/rdkls/gps-tracker-server
The data is coming as packets which are not over HTTP protocol. I have considered building a network listener over a socket on Google Compute Engine, but I'm not sure if it will be able to handle simultaneous requests from 1000 devices if such a situation ever arises. The Google Cloud IoT core offering seems to fit my need perfectly, but it is in private beta right now, which means I can't use it. I think I'll need a message queue service. But most of the offerings from these three companies requires messages over HTTP. Keep in mind that I can't change how the messages are sent from the GPS devices.
The messages sent are in this format - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2EklrIn3KugS2NJYWZGWlVWeGdMbjM4WHQ2TUZmYWhIRmt3/view?usp=drive_web
Format: 
data is sent in (byte sized) packets directly to the IP:Port over GPRS connections, one heartbeat packet every minute and GPS details every minute from each device. It also requires teh server to eply to the messagee for acknowledgement since it's not over TCP/IP.

So basically, which service and which architecture should I use keeping scalability, reliability and cost in mind?
I think for a 1000 devices, that would send such messages every minute, total would be 43M messages. I'm not sure but I'm looking for something that'll cost me about 1000$ that is 1$ per device per month.

Comment: Please explain or show the format with your question rather than using a link. Additionally please specific your range of acceptable cost, and your required reliability as a percentage of uptime or other measure.

Comment: @this.josh is this okay, as for reliability I think a message queue service would be good enough as it would store all the messages which can be processed and stored in a a database later